# Printing a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to print a `datagridview` which will get values from the database, I was able to do that but I don't know why the columns name are not showing up after I print it. Below is the code that I am currently using:

This one is for the printdocument:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        With DataGridView3
            Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
            Dim text As String = ("TrashCollection - Estatísticas")
            fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 350, 30)
            Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
            Do While mRow < DataGridView3.RowCount
                Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                Dim h As Single = 0
                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                    If (newpage) Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView3.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    Else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView3.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    End If
                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                Next
                newpage = False
                y += h
                mRow += 1
                If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    mRow -= 0
                    newpage = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Loop
            mRow = 0
        End With
    End Sub
```

And then into the print button I have this lines of code:

```
Private Sub cmdPrintDetailed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrintDetailed.Click
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

So, basically I would like to be able to print the columns name too instead of just the rows. Almost forget, in the print preview I am able to see all the the `datagridview` with the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best printing example I found and I use it modified for my datagrid printing. May be this will help you asit addesses also column headers.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBNet-Printing-Example-bc3b0176

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help, but this works with data from database?

Comment: Well, once the data is in the datagridview there shouldn't be any problem. Just compare the code with your code. The code from the link also prints wider than A4 and longer than A4 for example. Just load the example down and run it.

Comment: While I was trying to use that code it gave me an error on the Preview button called `object reference not set as an instance...`what do I do?

Comment: What do  you mean by use it? Did you try to run it as downloaded or did you try to run it modified in your program? I first ran it as it was downloaded and it ran without a problem.

Comment: I already found a better solution for what I really want...The code that I've found is more complex but it is better